# Putting 2 images in option of drop-down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was trying to put 2 images in a option-tag of a dropdown-box.
One image works with the background-image porperty.
So I tried the following code but its not working.
What is the best way to do this?

```
<select>
    <option>
       <img src="fist.jpg" height="10" width="10"/>
       <img src="second.jpg" height="10" width="10"/>
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can't put images in an option tag.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html)

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can use multiple background images in CSS3.

```
background-image: url(first.jpg), url(second.jpg);
```